# Definition of the "support" of the reduced density matrix

Tags: operators, quantum-information, terminology, linear-algebra, density-operator

Some of the papers in condensed matter physics use the word "support" (space).
For example, the following papers use the support especially for the reduced density matrix.

http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.83.035107
http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2260

I guess they use the support as the orthogonal subspace of the kernel of the reduced density matrix $\rho$.
However, according to the Wikipedia the definition of support is
${\rm supp}(\rho) := \{ x\ |\ \rho(x) \neq 0 \}$.
And this is not equivalent to the orthogonal subspace of the kernel in general.

What is the definition of the support of the reduced density matrix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For linear operators, the support usually denotes the space which is orthogonal to the kernel (equivalently, the support is the space spanned by the rows of the matrix). Density operators are linear operators, and thus it is used in this sense in the papers you cite.

See also [this question at math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95559/is-support-of-an-operator-same-as-row-space) or [this book from a google search "support of a linear map"](https://books.google.de/books?id=TG-aayAYExoC&lpg=PA189&ots=VTsiKkevLa&dq=%22support%20of%20a%20linear%20map%22&hl=de&pg=PA189#v=onepage&q=%22support%20of%20a%20linear%20map%22&f=false)

Comment: Sorry, I think [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) is not the space spanned by the columns of the matrix, instead it should be the same as null space, i.e. ${\displaystyle \ker(L)=\left\{\mathbf {v} \in V\mid L(\mathbf {v} )=\mathbf {0} \right\}}$. The space spanned by the columns of the matrix should be the *range* of the matrix.

Comment: @narip The clause in brackets referred to "support", not to "kernel". I have clarified. I should have read "rows", though, although for hermitian operators such as those the question is about, it does not matter.