# What does "support of an observable" mean in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-information, observables

I am reading Preskill's lecture notes on quantum information. At one place he has written that the observables who live in a Hilbert space $H_A$ have access only to observables with support in $H_A$. In this context, what does "support" of an observable mean?

Link to lecture notes:
[http://theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph229/](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph229/)
Chapter 3, section 3.1.2

Comment: The observables would be zero everywhere else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definition of the "support" of the reduced density matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/209401/)

Answer (score 0):

In this context you need to refer to the mathematical concept of [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)).
The simplest way to think about it is that it represents a portion of the [domain of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) where the function does not go to zero in the [range of the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function).

To be more pedantic, you can look at [Rank Nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) for the specific context it is used in linear algebra, where it becomes important to understand the definition of a [Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)).  In linear systems the Kernel is the solution to set of homogenous linear equations (i.e. a set of row equations that map to zero; $Ax = 0$).  [In that context the "support" is "is the space spanned by the rows of the matrix".](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209401/definition-of-the-support-of-the-reduced-density-matrix)

[There is some difference though when considering finite versus infinite systems. Below is a good explanation](http://physics.mq.edu.au/%7Ejcresser/Phys301/Chapters/Chapter13.pdf):

> "For state spaces of finite dimension, the eigenvalues of any
> Hermitean operator are discrete, and the eigenvectors form a complete
> set of basis states. For state spaces of infinite dimension, it is
> possible for a Hermitean operator not to have a complete set of
> eigenvectors, so that it is possible for a system to be in a state
> which cannot be represented as a linear combination of the eigenstates
> of such an operator. In this case, the operator cannot be understood
> as being an observable as it would appear to be the case that the
> system could be placed in a state for which a measurement of the
> associated observable yielded no value! To put it another way, if a
> Hermitean operator could be constructed whose eigenstates did not form
> a complete set, then we can rightfully claim that such an operator
> cannot represent an observable property of the system.
>
> It should also be pointed out that it is quite possible to construct
> all manner of Hermitean operators to be associated with any given
> physical system. Such operators would have all the mathematical
> properties to be associated with their being Hermitean, but it is not
> necessarily the case that these represent either any readily
> identifiable physical feature of the system at least in part because
> it might not be at all apparent how such ‘observables’ could be
> measured."

The [requirement of completeness in quantum systems is important](https://people.chem.ucsb.edu/metiu/horia/OldFiles/QM2015/Ch3QM.pdf) as it tells us the probability of getting a result from measurement must equal 1 (e.g. there is always an outcome).

In the case of a [positive operator-valued measure (POVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM) the requirement for completeness manifests itself by having a linear set of Hermitian matrices (representing possible measurement outcomes) equal to the identity matrix. While there is some dancing about this point, the reality is that a linear combination equal to one is non-homogeneous ($Ax = 1$).

There is a subtle [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)), or perhaps a [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)), going on when one talks of a function's meaningful values only being available in the region of the domain where its supported.  In this context the statement can be taken to mean that an observable can only exist in the Hilbert space if there is another portion of the Hilbert space it can be mapped to.

This is pretty consistent with most modern interpretations of quantum physics and relates to the general observation that everything that one observer might know can be reduced to a probability in some other observer's frame of reference.  It is also consistent with the linear mechanics of the Hilbert Space within quantum mechanics.  This is the root of Everett's conundrum leading to his dissertation on [The Theory of the Universal Wave Function](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/manyworlds/pdf/dissertation.pdf).

> "To better illustrate the paradoxes which can arise from strict
> adherence to this interpretation we consider the following amusing,
> but extremely hypothetical drama. Isolated somewhere out in space is a
> room containing an observer, A, who is about to perform a measurement
> upon a system S. After performing his measurement, he will record the
> result in his notebook. We assume that he knows the state function of
> S (perhaps as a result of previous measurement), and that it is not an
> eigenstate of the measurement he is about to perform. A, being an
> orthodox quantum theorist, then believes that the outcome of his
> measurement is undetermined and that the process is correctly
> described by Process 1. In the meantime, however, there is another
> observer, B, outside the room, who is in possession of the state
> function of the entire room, including S, the measuring apparatus, and
> A, just prior to the measurement. B is only interested in what will be
> found in the notebook one week hence, so he computes the state
> function of the room for one week in the future according to Process
> 2. One week passes, and we find B still in possession of the state function of the room, which this equally orthodox quantum theorist
> believes to be a complete description of the room and its contents. If
> B's state function calculation tells beforehand exactly what is going
> to be in the notebook, then A is incorrect in his belief about the
> indeterminacy of the outcome of his measurement. We therefore assume
> that B's state function contains non-zero amplitudes over several of
> the notebook entries. At this point, B opens the door to the room and
> looks at the notebook (performs his observation). Having observed the
> notebook entry, he turns to A and informs him in a patronizing manner
> that since his (B's) wave function just prior to his entry into the
> room, which he knows to have been a complete description of the room
> and its contents, had non-zero amplitude over other than the present
> result of the measurement, the result must have been decided only when
> B entered the room, so that A, his notebook entry, and his memory
> about what occurred one week ago had no independent objective
> existence until the intervention by B. In short, B implies that A owes
> his present objective existence to B's generous nature which compelled
> him to intervene on his behalf. However, to B's consternation, A does
> not react with anything like the respect and gratitude he should
> exhibit towards B, and at the end of a somewhat heated reply, in which
> A conveys in a colorful manner his opinion of B and his beliefs, he
> rudely punctures B's ego by observing that if B's view is correct,
> then he has no reason to feel complacent, since the whole present
> situation may have no objective existence, but may depend upon the
> future actions of yet another observer."

Comment: This is not the correct definition for linear maps, i.e., in the context of quantum theory/quantum information.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch updates the answer